# Pandas Crosstab dos not support Float (with capital F) number formats

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a sample data transaction dataframe. Such base contains cliente ID, transaction gross value (GMV) and revenue. Take this example as DF :

```
num_variables = 100
rng = np.random.default_rng()
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id' :  np.random.randint(1,999999999,num_variables),
    'date' : [np.random.choice(pd.date_range(datetime(2022,6,1),datetime(2022,12,31))) for i in range(num_variables)],
    'gmv' : rng.random(num_variables) * 100,
    'revenue' : rng.random(num_variables) * 100})
```

I am grouping such data by client ID, crossing with transaction month and exhibiting revenue values.

```
clients = df[['id', 'date','revenue']].groupby(['id', df.date.dt.to_period("M")], dropna=False).aggregate({'revenue': 'sum'})
clients.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Now I create a crosstab

```
CrossTab = pd.crosstab(clients['id'], clients['date'], values=clients['revenue'], rownames=None, colnames=None, aggfunc='sum', margins=True, margins_name='All', dropna=False, normalize=False)
```

The code above works normally as my sample dataframe revenue is a "float64" dtype.
But it a change the dtype to Float64, it does not work anymore.

```
num_variables = 100
rng = np.random.default_rng()
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id' :  np.random.randint(1,999999999,num_variables),
    'date' : [np.random.choice(pd.date_range(datetime(2022,6,1),datetime(2022,12,31))) for i in range(num_variables)],
    'gmv' : rng.random(num_variables) * 100,
    'revenue' : rng.random(num_variables) * 100})
df = df.astype({'revenue':'Float64'})

clients = df[['id', 'date','revenue']].groupby(['id', df.date.dt.to_period("M")], dropna=False).aggregate({'revenue': 'sum'})
clients.reset_index(inplace=True)

CrossTab = pd.crosstab(clients['id'], clients['date'], values=clients['revenue'], rownames=None, colnames=None, aggfunc='sum', margins=True, margins_name='All', dropna=False, normalize=False)
```

The output

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[31], line 1
----> 1 CrossTab = pd.crosstab(clients['id'], clients['date'], values=clients['revenue'], rownames=None, colnames=None, aggfunc='sum', margins=True, margins_name='All', dropna=False, normalize=False)

File c:\Users\F3164582\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py:691, in crosstab(index, columns, values, rownames, colnames, aggfunc, margins, margins_name, dropna, normalize)
    688     df["__dummy__"] = values
    689     kwargs = {"aggfunc": aggfunc}
--> 691 table = df.pivot_table(
    692     "__dummy__",
    693     index=unique_rownames,
    694     columns=unique_colnames,
    695     margins=margins,
    696     margins_name=margins_name,
    697     dropna=dropna,
    698     **kwargs,
    699 )
    701 # Post-process
    702 if normalize is not False:

File c:\Users\F3164582\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:8728, in DataFrame.pivot_table(self, values, index, columns, aggfunc, fill_value, margins, dropna, margins_name, observed, sort)
   8711 @Substitution("")
   8712 @Appender(_shared_docs["pivot_table"])
   8713 def pivot_table(
   (...)
...
--> 292     raise TypeError(dtype)  # pragma: no cover
    294 converted = maybe_downcast_numeric(result, dtype, do_round)
    295 if converted is not result:

TypeError: Float64
```

Comment: I really didn't care about being the Float instead of float. My question is to understand why it does not support it. On my real data, Float format is currently in use, I started to get errors creating the crosstab and was investigating its cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´ve reported this issue on pandas github and still being analyzed.

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/50313